# How does one compute the resultant of two polynomials in Octave?

Tags: octave

Maple has a very clean way of computing the resultant of two polynomials:

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=resultant

Does this function have a counterpart in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scilab, you get it as the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of the two polynomials. As Scilab has a native polynomial datatype, it comes quite simply:

```
--> a = poly([1 2 3 4],"x","roots")
 a  = 
  24 -50x +35x² -10x³ +x⁴

--> b = poly([-2 -1 5],"x","roots")
 b  = 
  -10 -13x -2x² +x³

--> det(sylm(a,b))
 ans  =
   1036800.0
```

In Scilab, `sylm()` is in the `Polynomials` section. Apparently there is no equivalent in Octave's Polynomial chapter, nor in its control toolbox. May be elsewhere? Otherwise, you can edit the Scilab sylm() code, and transpose it into Octave. It is less than 20-line long, and simple. Since the Sylvester matrix is a numerical one, you then have just to apply the usual det() function to it.